Memory storage in the brain
So I asked Google,

how many neurons in the brain
how many neural connections in the brain

The answers were, respectively:

86 billion
100 trillion

There are, I think, 8,589,934,592 bits in one gigabyte. (Am I correct?)
100 trillion divided by this number gives us approx 11,642 GB of storage, assuming that:

One neural connection stores one bit (I'm not sure what that would even mean)
The entire brain is used for memory storage

11,000 GB sounds like a lot. Laptops these days can have around 100 GB of disk storage.
A 4K film can need about 15 GB per hour of film. So the number above gives approx 776 hours of "recorded film" memory. That's 32 days. This calculation tells us the brain can store about a month's worth of memories.
But a human memory (well, my memories at least - I can't vouch for others ;) isn't just a high quality vivid visual + audio "film" recording - it contains other bodily sensations (smell, movement, space, muscular sensation, temperature) and also emotions, speech, thoughts, conclusions, intentions and other less definite content.
Additionally, I have on occasion surprised myself with just how early I could remember. For example, with parents saying to me, aghast, "You remember that house?" So I reckon one month of storage is orders of magnitude insufficient.

Is my thinking on this even vaguely in the correct direction?
How do theories of physical memory storage account for this?
What's the best theory of human memory storage we currently have?
Do memory theories focus exclusively on the brain, or are there any "whole body" theories, or theories involving cellular memory?

(As you may be able to tell, I am a layman on this. I have high school biology, and undergrad level physics knowledge.)

Hi Stewart. You should stick to one question per post. Also, some of your questions are far to broad to answer in a medium like Stackexchange "What's the best theory of human memory storage we currently have" is not something that can be conveyed in a few paragraphs. Be sure to take the guided tour of the site  (listed under the help button) to see what questions are appropriate.

It doesn't make much sense to measure biological/neuronal memory the way you measure bits in computer memory. Connections aren't binary, we store things conceptually not like pixelwise video.

11000 GB can be easily less than a single hard disk. There were SSD in laptops as small as 128 GB, but they get cheaper and bigger. HDD at the time were much bigger.

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19614/is-there-any-size-limit-to-the-amount-of-information-a-human-or-other-brain-ca

The brain is much, much more sophisticated than a computer. Memory depends so much on so many things, from "working memory" available in any situation, to emotions associate with them, timing of synaptic pruning and even to olfactory-associated memories. This question is too broad. VTC.

Cellular memory? Here's stuff to look into: There's obviously DNA (and shortening telomeres with each cell division), but also search for "methylation" in relation to cell function.

Thank you all for these useful comments - particularly the leads of what to look up next.

@Mithoron Both questions which you linked, and their answers, are indeed helpful. Thank you.

There was this 2003 paper titled "Uncovering the Capacity of Human Memory" by Yingxu Wang et al. that estimated it at a whopping 10^8432 bits, based on synaptic connections
Current estimates are more like a few petabytes apparently.

Welcome syndrop. The paper is available on Researchgate and is titled "Discovering the capacity [....]". You can use the [edit] button to add the URL. It might be helpful if you were to summarize the contents to help explain how the number was derived also.

10^8432 bits is a huge number!

@Stewart And rather nonsensical. I doubt whole observable universe would be enough to store this much information.
